# Debian upgrade from Wheezy to Jessie fails on Amazon EC2

Tags: debian, apt, upgrade, udev

I have searched and read other debian upgrade threads, but my situation doesn't seem to match that described in the other questions on this topic.

I have a t1.micro instance of debian running on Amazon's EC2 service which has been humming along nicely for years. I also have a lot of experience with Debian, including upgrades starting before potato, so I had a good idea of what sort of things might go wrong. I [read about issues](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/release-notes/ch-information.en.html#systemd-upgrade-default-init-system) upgrading to systemd and *thought* I had an idea of what to expect.

After going through the usual process of `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get upgrade` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, the installation of `udev` is failing with:

```
 sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree
 Reading state information... Done
 You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 consolekit : Recommends: libpam-ck-connector but it is not installed
          Breaks: udev (< 204-1) but 175-7.2 is installed
 E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Subsequent attempts to run `sudo apt-get -f install` fail with kernel warnings:

```
 Preparing to unpack .../udev_215-17+deb8u1_i386.deb ...
 Since release 198, udev requires support for the following features   
in the running kernel [...]
```

(see [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/ZNs8QTPC) on `udev` with warnings about required kernel upgrades. In researching this, I understood that a current kernel was required.

```
% uname -a
Linux hostname 2.6.32-5-xen-686 #1 SMP Tue May 13 18:49:23 UTC 2014 i686 GNU/Linux 
% apt-cache search xen-686
linux-image-2.6.32-5-xen-686 - Linux 2.6.32 for modern PCs, Xen dom0 support
linux-image-xen-686 - Linux for modern PCs (meta-package), Xen dom0 support

% sudo apt-get install linux-image-xen-686
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
linux-image-xen-686 is already the newest version.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
consolekit : Recommends: libpam-ck-connector but it is not going to be installed
          Breaks: udev (< 204-1) but 175-7.2 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I seem to be stuck. I tried `sudo apt-get install libpam-ck-connector` but get only the "try apt-get -f install" message.

This is installed on an EC2 t1.micro instance that I am migrating to a fresh jessie install on a t2.instance. Unfortunately, it uses a elasticip address that cannot be migrated to a t2 instance (which I only realized after the fact), so I want to keep this running for my mail server until I've completed the migration.

I am unable to update any packages or move forward. I can log in and edit configs, pull files and backups as necessary, so it's not a complete disaster. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just upgraded our old AWS PV instance from Squeeze (Debian 6) to Wheezy (Debian 7) and subsequently to Jessie (Debian 8). Our instance is `m1.large`, but it should be relevant as it's also the legacy paravirtualized type.

Since Wheezy there are no more special `-xen` kernel images - the standard kernel images support running in Xen dom0. So the solution is to install [the latest `linux-image-3.2.0-x-amd64` package **from Wheezy**](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64). Unfortunately the Jessie kernel image `linux-image-3.16.0-x-amd64` is compressed using xz and Amazon AWS cannot boot it - it reports the following error:

```
ERROR Invalid kernel: xc_dom_probe_bzimage_kernel: unknown compression format
```

However, Jessie seems to be running quite happily with the 3.2 kernel from Wheezy.

Comment: I finally bit the bullet and built a new t2.micro instance and converted over. Amazon was quick about allocating me the elasticip address, so I was able to keep the old instance limping along for a couple of days until the conversion was complete. Unfortunately, I can't test your solution, but it would have been a good option to try.